# USB not communicating with my LPC2478

Tags: c, usb-drive

I have been tasked at my new job with figuring out why their **LPC2478**  based instrument using a USB driver from way way before my time here, doesn't communicate sometimes (more often than not these days) with USB flash drives.   We have been having increasingly difficult time finding USBs that work.  The latest error the software just kicks out when you ask it to read a file off the USB.

I have hooked up the debugger and followed the error all the way down to

`usbhost_lcp248.c` (not sure where they got this from ) where:

```
if(!(TDHead->Control & 0xF0000000)
   return(OK);
else
  return (ERR_TD_FAIL);   -- which it always does!
```

the debugger shows the actual value to `TDHead->Control = 0x5E040000`

I've got a **5** instead of an **F**.

So...

Any help pointing me in any direction is much appreciated. I'm not even sure what this `TDHead->Control` is.

Sincerely,
Dubs

Comment: The `if` is malformed (missing paren). Is this an actual code? And I would just compare the masked thing to zero rather than messing with `!`.

Comment: Isn't there a copyright banner? At any rate bit of googling turned up the [LPC USB MSC sample](http://www.lpcware.com/content/project/nxp-peripherals/usb-nxp-microcontrollers/usb-host-mass-storage-class-msc-example), a later revision of which substitutes `!HOST_TDControlStatus` as that condition.

Comment: @Eugene Sh: Take care with the precedence of the `&` operator though.

Comment: Hello doynax,  have tried the later revision with the !HOST_TDControlStatus but it also fails in the same way.

Comment: I apologize for posting incomplete code (missing paren) it may lead one to believe it's a C coding problem but it's not.   This code works for some USB flash drives and others it does not.  Typos in posting aside - this code has been used for years, and as time progresses it works less and less with new flash devices.   When it works the Host_ProcessTD() function returns a descriptor the code recognizes, when it fails it fails in the way described above.